# How to go back (to the search results view) when executing a deletion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

As you can see in this picture (http://bit.ly/18nCejS) I have a search view, which leads to a results view and then to a product detail view.

My issue is that I don't know how to go back to the results page when I delete the product I'm showing.

The search results view is a dynamic view (based on the parameters selected on the search form) so it has to be "refreshed" (because the deleted product doesn't exist anymore)

Does anyone know how to get this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your views are different methods in your controller then you can use:

```
redirect_to :back
```

Otherwise, you'll probably have to deal with this in JS (ajax request).

Comment: Yes, they are on the same controller, but it doesn't work for me. I have updated destroy method with "redirect_to :back" but I get an error tring to view the deleted product.

It seems as "redirect_to :back" goes back 1 step (go to the product details view) but it needs to go back 2 steps.

Is there another way to do this? Maybe save the dynamic URL (the one that display the search results) and redirect to that URL?

Comment: Can't you simply redirect to the `index` action ?

Comment: I don't want to show all products (that is what index action shows) but to show only the results of the previous search

Comment: How do you access the results of the "previous" search ?

Comment: @Pierre-Louis This is the URL type I get http://localhost:3000/search?name=car&color=red&commit=Search

Comment: You should be able to do `redirect_to search_path(params)`

Comment: It seems params is not populated at that moment.

Anyway I have been able to save the URL using session[:prev_url] = request.url and restoring it later.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to handle deletions with AJAX, especially in a situation like this. 
Just make a lint to destroy action look something like

```
= link_to "Delete", model, :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure?"
```

- `model` is your itteration object.

Then in jour controller do

```
def delete 
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])
  @model.destroy
  render :js => "$('#result_line_#{@model.id}').remove();"  
end
```

- `Model` is the name of the class
- `#result_line_#{@model.id}` is the css selector for that line in the search results view.